# Using VLOOKUP in Excel VBA to import Image into Image Box

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am new to excel VBA but I'm trying to create a VLOOKUP that can look up entries for different days. I am only getting an error when it comes to loading the image based on the VLOOKUP result box. The path of the picture is stored in the same excel file and the picture comes from my PC

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a way for me to use Vlookup for excel via to display the actually images into a image box by using the picture path that's located in excel?